# QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError when running outside IDE

Tags: c++, qt, networking, deployment

I have the following code:

```
QNetworkAccessManager nam;
QEventLoop loop;
QNetworkRequest request(_client.url());
QNetworkReply *reply = nam.get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();

info = QSharedPointer<UpdateInformation>(new UpdateInformation(reply));
reply->deleteLater();
```

This code works fine when executed from Qt Creator, even when another application that runs in the IDE invokes this one (via QProcess).

However, when ran outside the IDE, the `QNetworkReply` is empty (its `length()` is 0). I'm assuming this is caused by a misplaced/wrong version dependency. I copied the needed DLLs from **c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\bin** and the application runs just fine. How can I find out which DLLs the IDE actually uses to run it? If that's not the problem, how can I gain more information?

Edit: after restructuring the code to connect to QNetworkAccessManager's `finished()` signal, I found that the `reply->error()` is `QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError`. I still have no clue about the cause though.

Solution (it won't let me answer it and there no way I'll wait 6 hours from now):

Ok, so I managed to solve it. The clue was **reply->errorString()** which said "Error creating SSL context ()". That quickly led me to remember that the URL was actually a HTTPS url. After a little digging around I found that in order to use the SSL functionality in Qt (and so HTTPS), one needs to copy the following openssl DLLs to the application folder: **libeay32.dll** and **ssleay32.dll**. And that's it.

Comment: post the solution as an answer. you are allowed to do it

Comment: you should edit your question and post the last paragraph as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from the author (he posted it as answer in his question, but this is easy to oversee):

> Ok, so I managed to solve it. The clue was **reply->errorString()**
>   which said "Error creating SSL context ()". That quickly led me to
>   remember that the URL was actually a HTTPS url. After a little digging
>   around I found that in order to use the SSL functionality in Qt (and
>   so HTTPS), one needs to copy the following openssl DLLs to the
>   application folder: **libeay32.dll** and **ssleay32.dll**. And that's
>   it.